# Script for BOM with multiple same item that need to be merged

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to coding, and working with google sheets and trying to write a script (or some other combination of formulas) that will spit out a BOM on a new sheet tab with all qty merged (we have multiple line items with the same part number with different qty and need them all merged to 1 line with total qty. I've highlighted columns I would like to have shown on my BOM sheet:

[image]

I've looked at Query function and other formulas/scripts but just cant seem to get it to work to pull what I want and sum the qty all in 1.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time you post a question, please provide the complete and verifiable example of the things you tried, including QUERY function parameters and / or scripts.

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

According to the query language syntax,

> If you use a group by clause, then every column listed in the select clause must either be listed in the group by clause, or be wrapped by an aggregation function.

[More on the visual query language used by Google in the QUERY function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#group-by)

In your case, the query will look like this

```
=QUERY(A2:P, "SELECT A,B,C,E,SUM(G),O,SUM(P) GROUP BY A,B,C,E,O")
```